# tkinter in python 3.6 on windows modal windows blocking deiconify functions

Tags: tkinter, modal-dialog, windows-10, python-3.6

python 3.6.1, windows 10, tkinter
when minimizing an application with a currently open modal window (by shaking a window around or clicking the show desktop button) it will block all efforts to maximize/deiconify/restore the window leaving it stuck withdrawn

already googled extensively and it seems it was an issue that has been 'resolved' back in python 2.7 and testing under windows 7 this in not an issue on 3.6.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.button = tk.Button(master, text='open modal', command=self.openModal)
        self.button.pack()

    def openModal(self):
        self.modal = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.modal.wm_transient(self.master)
        self.modal.grab_set()

        self.deiconifyButton = tk.Button(self.modal, text='deiconify me', command=self.master.deiconify)
        self.deiconifyButton.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

the window should deicionify both windows with the focus still forced onto the modal window, but the modal window just blocks all attempt to deiconify the root window

EDIT:
link to the bug report that has others questioning the completness of the fix: https://bugs.python.org/issue26340
[image: demo]

Comment: I also see this issue on python 3.7.3 on windows 10

Comment: it appears as this isn't going to get fixed any time soon, bug report got passed up on the bug tracker.